# How to Remove an element from HashSet?

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I want to remove an element from a HashSet.
Can sb help me to understand, why cat "emma" cant be removed from this HashSet?
What could be the best solution?

Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashSet<Cat> set = new HashSet<Cat>();
    
    set.add(new Cat("cindy"));
    set.add(new Cat("emma"));
    
    Iterator<Cat> iterator = set.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Cat name1 = iterator.next();

        if (name1.equals("emma")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(set);
}

public static class Cat {
    private String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Cat` is never equal to a `String`, unless you've defined a really broken equals method. Perhaps you want something like `Cat cat = iterator.next(); if (cat.toString().equals("emma")) { ... }`?

Comment: `set.removeIf(cat -> cat.toString().equals("ema"));`

Comment: Thank you both :)
Jon: I havent defined any equals method, only this what I posted ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `equals` method of a Cat with a string as an argument, which returns false. You can use the `toString` method as you have overridden it, or have a `getter` for the name and compare it with the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean equals(Object anObject)
```

Pay attention, that `equals` method accepts `Objects`, so you do not get an exception when two variables are not `String` as you expect (by the way, IntelliJ IDEA gives you an inspection for this case). All you need to fix it is to compare `String "emma"` with `name1.name`:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Cat name1 = it.next();

    if ("emma".equals(name1.toString()))
        it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see your problem running the following code:

```
Cat c = new Cat("emma");
if(c.equals("emma"))
    System.out.println("true"); // this is what you expect
else
    System.out.println("false!"); // this is what actually happens!
```

This is because if the `equals` method is not defined, by default it compares that the two objects are exactly the same. You can find more information about this behavior [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). In your case you are comparing a `String` object with a `Cat` object.

One possible solution would be to use the `toString` method you hava defined in your class to compare between strings. The `equals` method is overridden in the `String` class to have the behavior you expect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashSet<Cat> set = new HashSet<Cat>();
    
    set.add(new Cat("cindy"));
    set.add(new Cat("emma"));
    
    Iterator<Cat> iterator = set.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Cat name1 = iterator.next();

        if (name1.toString().equals("emma")) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

Another solution could be to override the `equals` method in your cat class. Here is a way you could do it:

```
import java.util.*;

class Cat {
    private String name;

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public Boolean equals(Cat other) {
        return this.name.equals(other.name);
    }
}
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<Cat> set = new HashSet<Cat>();
    
    Cat cindy = new Cat("cindy");
    Cat emma = new Cat("emma");

    set.add(cindy);
    set.add(emma);
    
    Iterator<Cat> iterator = set.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Cat cat = iterator.next();

        if (cat.equals(emma)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this code would remove the item even if `equals` wasn't defined because the default implementation compares identity. A better illustration would be `if (cat.equals(new Cat("emma")))` which only works if `equals is defined`